# Prevent to copy & paste in masked edit text-box in C#/vb.net

Tags: c#

How to prevent to copy & paste any text [using right click and also Ctrl+C and Ctrl+v keys] in masked edit text-box in C#/vb.net?

Comment: I haven't had need to use the masked edit text box but, it seems like preventing copy/paste go hand in hand with masking the text. It really doesn't block it or at least provide a setting to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherit from `TextBox` and override the `WndProc` method :

```
private const int WM_CUT = 0x0300;
private const int WM_COPY = 0x0301;
private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

protected override void WndProc(ref Messsage m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_CUT || m.Msg == WM_COPY || m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        return;
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

It should also prevent copy/paste from the context menu

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by replacing the default context menu with your own context menu to disable mouse clicks and then you could just stop any keyboard input while the Control key is pressed by handling the KeyDown event and writing code like:

```
If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

for ctrl+v/c You need to inherit the TextBox class and override the function `ProcessCmdKey`
and then call base class only if ctrl+c or ctrl+v are not pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Set ShortcutsEnabled property of textbox to False.
Drawbacks:
This will also prevent Ctrl+A and Right Click Menu of that textbox.